# CSS Columns IE issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a weird issue with CSS columns under IE10.

css:

```
.columns {
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count: 2;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 400px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

When the number of items is odd everything is fine, but when I've got an even number of items the top one is spit between two columns. Please see image

[image]

Please see here plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/8aKV6kHjhAIhRF26ZU0v?p=preview

Comment: can you show any other css effecting the elements (or better yet a jsfiddle?)

Comment: don't use column-count

Comment: I've added link to plunkr

Answer (score 0):

column-count is working only >=IE10

Comment: The problem is under IE10 & IE11